# How to split AWS cloud watch event data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Need to split AWS cloud watch event data due to the 256K data limit size.
Tried splitting it - does not work - only the last chunk shows up.

Any technique around this

Comment: Could you show your effort and tell us more about what you've tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "CloudWatch event data"? And what do you mean by the 256K data limit? Or are you referring to sending messages to an Amazon SQS queue?